# Contando elementos criados dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o JS abaixo que via `$.ajax` faz a leitura em arquivo PHP e cria `div`'s dinâmicas.

```
function insere_inversor() {
  
    $.ajax({      
      method: "POST",
      url: BASE_URL + 'ajax/inversores',
      headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
      data: { url: BASE_URL},
      success: function (result) {
        $("div.inversores").append(result);
      }
    });
    
}

$(document).on('click', 'button.addInversor', function(e) {
    insere_inversor()
    console.log($('button.subInversor').length)
    e.preventDefault();
})

$(document).on('click', 'button.subInversor', function(e) {
    $(this).closest("div.inversor").remove()
    console.log($('button.subInversor').length)
    e.preventDefault();
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('button.subInversor').length === 1) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Após criar essas `div`'s, tem dentro delas um botão para excluir.
Mas como elas estão sendo criadas dinamicamente eu não sei se estou contando certo!

A ideia é, à medida em que as `div`'s que forem criadas vão sendo removidas, a ficar apenas uma, o botão de **remover** seja **desabilitado** pois é obrigatório ter pelo menos uma `div`.

Segue a criação da **DIV** no **PHP**

```
public function inversores() {        
            
    $inversores = $this->Model_produtos_inversores->listar_inversores();
            
    $options = "";
    if (count($inversores) > 0) 
        foreach($inversores as $inversor) 
            $options.= "<option  value='"  . $inversor->id . "'>"  . $inversor->modelo . "</option>";
    else 
            $options = "<option value=''>Sem inversores cadastrados</option>";

    echo   "<div class='inversor'>
                <input type='int' name='qtd_inversor[]' placeholder='Quantidade'>
                <select name='inversores[]'>" . $options . "</select> 
                <button class='addInversor'>+</button>
                <button class='subInversor'>-</button>
            </div>";
}
```

Comment: Agradecido pela edição e aguardando orientações. Feliz Natal!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para desabilitar o botão de remover do único remanescente de um conjunto de elementos pode usar a [pseudo-classe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) CSS [`:only-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type) que representa qualquer elemento que não possui irmãos de um determinado tipo.

O raciocínio é simples, se dentro do `<div class="inversores">` existir apenas `<div>` sem irmãos então desabilite os [eventos de ponteiro](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) para o botão `<button class='subInversor'>-</button>`

```js
//Simula o código original para ser usado em testes.
function insere_inversor() {
  $("div.inversores").append(`<div class='inversor'>
  <input type='int' name='qtd_inversor[]' placeholder='Quantidade'>
  <select name='inversores[]'>" . $options . "</select> 
  <button class='addInversor'>+</button>
  <button class='subInversor'>-</button>
</div>`);
}

//Réplica do código original porém sem parte do console.log() 
$(document).on('click', 'button.addInversor', function(e) {
  insere_inversor()
  e.preventDefault();
})

//Réplica do código original porém sem parte do console.log()
$(document).on('click', 'button.subInversor', function(e) {
  $(this).closest("div.inversor").remove()
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.inversores :only-of-type>.subInversor {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inversores">
  <div class='inversor'>
    <input type='int' name='qtd_inversor[]' placeholder='Quantidade'>
    <select name='inversores[]'>" . $options . "</select>
    <button class='addInversor'>+</button>
    <button class='subInversor'>-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

O problema da abordagem acima é que o botão `<button class='subInversor'>-</button>` ainda pode ser focado usando o teclado, clicando no select com o mouse e navegar até ele com a tecla `tab`.

Então uma patch seria usar o atributo [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) com o valor `-1` significando que o elemento não deve ser localizado pela navegação sequencial do teclado.

```js
//Simula o código original para ser usado em testes com tabindex="-1".
function insere_inversor() {
  $("div.inversores").append(`<div class='inversor'>
  <input type='int' name='qtd_inversor[]' placeholder='Quantidade'>
  <select name='inversores[]'>" . $options . "</select> 
  <button class='addInversor'>+</button>
  <button tabindex="-1" class='subInversor'>-</button>
</div>`);
}

//Réplica do código original porém sem parte do console.log() 
$(document).on('click', 'button.addInversor', function(e) {
  insere_inversor()
  e.preventDefault();
})

//Réplica do código original porém sem parte do console.log()
$(document).on('click', 'button.subInversor', function(e) {
  $(this).closest("div.inversor").remove()
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.inversores :only-of-type>.subInversor {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inversores">
  <div class='inversor'>
    <input type='int' name='qtd_inversor[]' placeholder='Quantidade'>
    <select name='inversores[]'>" . $options . "</select>
    <button class='addInversor'>+</button>
    <button tabindex="-1" class='subInversor'>-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Outra abordagem ainda em CSS é desabilitar a exibição do elemento estilizando sua propriedade [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display) com o valor `none`.

```js
//Simula o código original para ser usado em testes.
function insere_inversor() {
  $("div.inversores").append(`<div class='inversor'>
  <input type='int' name='qtd_inversor[]' placeholder='Quantidade'>
  <select name='inversores[]'>" . $options . "</select> 
  <button class='addInversor'>+</button>
  <button class='subInversor'>-</button>
</div>`);
}

//Réplica do código original porém sem parte do console.log() 
$(document).on('click', 'button.addInversor', function(e) {
  insere_inversor()
  e.preventDefault();
})

//Réplica do código original porém sem parte do console.log()
$(document).on('click', 'button.subInversor', function(e) {
  $(this).closest("div.inversor").remove()
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.inversores :only-of-type>.subInversor {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inversores">
  <div class='inversor'>
    <input type='int' name='qtd_inversor[]' placeholder='Quantidade'>
    <select name='inversores[]'>" . $options . "</select>
    <button class='addInversor'>+</button>
    <button class='subInversor'>-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou. Eu não conhecia esse recurso. Vou anotar aqui! Obrigado. Mas rá que teria como também substituir o valor "-" por uma imagem usando o próprio css?

Comment: @CarlosRocha, Feliz Natal!

Comment: @CarlosRocha, fiz algumas correções na resposta. Quando fala em substituir o valor "-" por uma imagem, seria realmente uma imagem ou outro caractere?

Comment: uma imagem. Aquela de um circulo com cortado!

Comment: [`background-image: url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

Comment: Muito, mas muito obrigado mesmo! achei essa abordem .inversores :only-of-type>.subInversor {
  display: none;
} mas interessante para mim. E sobre o background, ficou melhor remover o botão que colocar uma imagem e bloquear